# Error with Django application on Cloud Run using Cloud SQL PostgreSQL DB - cannot connect to database

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have this Django project on Google Cloud on Cloud Run. It is *supposed to* connect to the Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database and work, but it doesn't. Here is the database part of `settings.py` (I have removed the private data):

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {   
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME': 'db',
      'USER': 'user',
      'PASSWORD': 'password',
      'HOST': '/cloudsql/project:europe-west4:instance',
      'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do anything database-related (for example, log in), it throws the error

```
OperationalError at /accounts/login/
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/*project*:europe-west4:*instance*/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

If I remove the `/cloudsql/` from HOST it gives the error

```
OperationalError at /accounts/login/
could not translate host name "*project*:europe-west4:*instance*" to address: Name or service not known
```

When I use the Cloud SQL proxy exe to test on my local computer it works. However, when I deploy it to Cloud Run it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled connecting to that Cloud SQL instance from Cloud Run?

Try running

```
gcloud run services update [your cloud run service name] \
  --add-cloudsql-instances [project:region:instance]
```

Also check that your Cloud Run service account has `Cloud SQL Client` permissions. See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#configuring) for more information on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full url in `host` parameter

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of the 'full url'

Comment: Sure, use some thing like `postgres://<hostname>/path`, or use an external library for better compability eg: dj-database-url https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/

Comment: But then, what is the host name going to be? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions.

Comment: You need to reffer your cloud provider's settings for that.